# Problemas al insertar datos de un archivo json a BD mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, base-de-datos

Mi problema es que intento ingresar los datos de un archivo JSON a mi bd mysql pero solo se agregan ciertos registros y ahí mi duda.

¿Por qué no se agregan todos los registros?  y no se como encontrar el error.

anteriormente lo he hecho con muchos archivos JSON y no me había encontrado con este problema. El siguiente es mi codigo PHP.

```
    <?php

  require('db.php');
  include 'obtenerImagen.php';
  $json = file_get_contents("../json/archivo.json");

  $conexion = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $databaseName) 
  or die("Ha sucedido un error inesperado en la conexion de la base de datos");

  $noticiasData = json_decode($json, true);

  foreach ($noticiasData as $noticias) {

    $titulo = $noticias['title']['__cdata'];
    $link = $noticias['link'];
    $img = obtenerImg($noticias['description']['__cdata']); 
    $fecha = str_replace("T"," ",$noticias['date']['__text']);
    $fecha = substr($fecha, 0,19);
    $descripcion = $noticias['description']['__cdata'];

    mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO fullNews (titulo,link,img,fecha, descripcion) VALUES ('$titulo', '$link', '$img', '$fecha', '$descripcion')");
        
  } 

  mysqli_close($conexion);

 ?>
```

Si imprimo los resultados, me muestra todos los registros correctamente pero en la base de datos solo se agrega uno.

Aqui el archivo JSON:

```
[
     
     {
        "title": {
           "__cdata": "Famosos 'gamer': la cantante Lady Gaga, fan de 'Bayonetta', se suma al club de los aficionados por los videojuegos"
        },
        "link": "https://www.20minutos.es/videojuegos/noticia/famosos-gamer-cantante-lady-gaga-club-aficionados-videojuegos-3482700/0/",
        "description": {
           "__cdata": "<p>INÉS LÓPEZ</p> <ul><li>La artista escribió un tuit en el que contaba que se había pasado el cuarto capítulo de 'Bayonetta'.</li><li>Otros famosos que son reconocidos 'gamers' son Megan Fox, Matthew Perry y Daniel Craig.</li></ul><p><img src=\"https://cdn.20m.es/img2/recortes/2018/11/05/817731-620-282.jpg?v=20181105130414\" width=\"620\" height=\"282\" alt=\"Lady Gaga y Bayonetta\" /></p><p>La cantante más extravagante de Estados Unidos,<a href=\"https://www.20minutos.es/minuteca/lady-gaga/\"><strong> Lady Gaga </strong></a>ha desvelado a través de su cuenta de Twitter su <strong>afición por los <a href=\"https://www.20minutos.es/videojuegos/minuteca/videojuegos/\">videojuegos</a></strong>. En concreto, ha comentado que está disfrutando del título <em>Bayonetta,</em> recientemente lanzado en <a href=\"https://www.20minutos.es/videojuegos/minuteca/nintendo-switch/\">Nintendo Switch</a>.</p><p>En su tuit ha celebrado que <strong>ha conseguido terminar el cuarto capítulo del juego</strong> sin especificar en qué plataforma lo está jugando (<em>Bayonetta</em> debutó en 2010 en PlayStation 3 y Xbox 360, apareció en Wii U en 2014 y hace poco ha llegado a Nintendo Switch).</p><p>Independientemente,<strong> la compañía <a href=\"https://www.20minutos.es/videojuegos/minuteca/nintendo/\">Nintendo</a> ha respondido a la artista</strong> a través de su cuenta americana para darle ánimos para que supere con éxito el quinto capítulo del videojuego.</p><div><blockquote class=\"twitter-tweet\" data-lang=\"es\"><p dir=\"ltr\">You got this! </p>— Nintendo of America (@NintendoAmerica) <a href=\"https://twitter.com/NintendoAmerica/status/1059125879605911552?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw\">4 de noviembre de 2018</a></blockquote></div><h2>Los famosos también juegan</h2><p>Lady Gaga es una más en la extensa <strong>lista de famosos</strong> que han mostrado públicamente su afición por los videojuegos. Cantantes, actores, directores, celebrities... Son muchos los que dedican su tiempo libre a la industria <em>gamer</em>.</p><h3>Megan Fox</h3><p>La actriz de <em>Transformers</em>, <a href=\"https://www.20minutos.es/minuteca/megan-fox/\">Megan Fox</a>, ha dicho en más de una ocasión ser una gran jugadora, de hecho, podría haberte dado una paliza en Xbox Live jugando a <em>Halo</em>, ya que le encanta este título, <strong>su favorito de la franquicia es <em>Halo: Reach</em>.</strong> Sin embargo, Fox ha evitado a toda costa desvelar su nombre usuario ya que considera divertido ver como muchos jugadores se meten con ella o le hacen bromas sin imaginarse quién está al otro lado del jugador.</p><h3>Samuel L. Jackson</h3><p>Si juegas a la saga <em>Grand Theft Auto</em> puede que te hayas cruzado con el que encarna al jefazo de <em>Los Vengadores (</em>Nick Furia), <strong><a href=\"https://www.20minutos.es/minuteca/samuel-l-jackson/\">Samuel L. Jackson</a>. El actor es un declarado fan</strong> de los videojuegos, ha participado en varios eventos de la industria (como los VGA 2012) y es un apasionado de la saga creada por Rockstar Games.</p><h3>George Lucas</h3><p>El artífice de la saga espacial más famosa del cine (<em>Star Wars</em>), <strong><a href=\"https://www.20minutos.es/minuteca/george-lucas/\">George Lucas</a>, es otro de los <em>gamers</em> famosos</strong> que ha declarado abiertamente su pasión por los videojuegos.  El director ha dicho en más de una entrevista que es un gran amante de la industria aunque también ha hecho declaraciones un tanto polémicas, defendiendo que lo que importa en un juego para que sea bueno es su propia naturaleza y no su trama.</p><h3>Matthew Perry</h3><p>¿Recuerdas a Chandler, de <em>Friends?</em> Seguro que no sabías que <a href=\"https://www.20minutos.es/minuteca/matthew-perry/\">el actor</a> tuvo que ser intervenido quirúrgicamente al <strong>hacerse daño en las manos de tanto jugar al <em>Fallout III</em>,</strong> videojuego del que el actor se enamoró. Cuando se enteraron, los creadores de la saga le ofrecieron un papel en su juego <em>Fallout: New Vegas.</em></p><h3>Will Arnett</h3><p>Otro actor del que no nos sorprendemos por su afición a los videojuegos es<strong> Will Arnett</strong> (<em>Tortugas Ninja, Arrested Development)</em>, que organizó un <strong>grupo secreto de <em>gamers</em> en Hollywood</strong> para jugar a la Xbox. Con él pasan el rato a los mandos Justin Theroux, Jason Sudeikis y Jerry O'Connel, entre otros.</p><h3>Mila Kunis</h3><p>Conocida como Jackie en <em>That's 70's Show</em> o como la voz de Meg Griffin en <em>Padre de Familia</em>, <strong><a href=\"https://www.20minutos.es/minuteca/mila-kunis/\">Kunis</a> es una gran jugadora de <em>Call of Duty: Black Ops II</em>.</strong> El Modo Zombie le provocó curiosidad y desde que lo probó no ha podido dejar de jugar.</p><h3>Kim Kardasian</h3><p>La <a href=\"https://www.20minutos.es/minuteca/kim-kardashian/\">celebrity norteamericana</a> se unió a la lista de famosos aficionados a los videojuegos<strong> gracias a los títulos <em>Rock Band</em> y <em>Call of Duty. </em></strong>Hace unos años la actriz tuiteó \"esperaba con muchas ganas el lanzamiento del juego\", refiriendose al <em>Call of Duty: Black Ops II</em>, en el momento de su estreno.</p><h3>Daniel Craig</h3><p>Sí, el James Bond más malote de la saga dedica su tiempo libre a los videojuegos. Es<strong> un apasionado de</strong> <strong><em>Guitar Hero</em> y de <em>Halo</em></strong>. Además, <a href=\"https://www.20minutos.es/minuteca/daniel-craig/\">el actor</a> reconoció en una entrevista que este <em>hobby</em> le causó más de un problema con su expareja.</p><h3>Ice-T</h3><p>El famoso rapero norteamericano es tan amante de los videojuegos como del hip-hop. Ha contado varias veces que <strong>pasó su infancia entre la Atari y las consolas de Sega</strong> y que sus sagas predilectas son <em>Mortal Kombat</em> y <em>NBA</em><em> Jam</em>.</p><h3>Snoop Dogg</h3><p>Otro rapero <em>gamer</em> es Calvin Cordozar, conocido como <a href=\"https://www.20minutos.es/minuteca/snoop-dogg/\">Snoop Dogg</a>, que pasa horas y horas delante de la televisión<strong> jugando a los <em>Call of Duty. </em></strong>En 2006 creó su propio grupo de jugadores llamado Hip-hop Gaming League.</p><h3>Eminem</h3><p>Junto con los anteriores, <a href=\"https://www.20minutos.es/minuteca/eminem/\">Eminem</a> se suma a los raperos aficionados por los videojuegos. Disfruta siendo <strong>la melodía de los <em>Call of Duty</em></strong> pero también jugándolos. Le gusta echarse unas partidas <em>online</em> y, por lo que dicen, no se le da nada mal repartir balazos.</p><h3>Cameron Diaz</h3><p>Aunque suene imposible, la actriz y modelo estadounidense es una auténtica adicta a <em>World of Warcraft</em>. <a href=\"https://www.20minutos.es/minuteca/cameron-diaz/\">Diaz</a> ha comentado en numerosas ocasiones su pasión por el título de Blizzard e incluso ha llegado a decir que jugar a videojuegos es una de las actividades que más le gusta de su vida.</p><h3>Gemma Atkinson</h3><p>La modelo de ropa interior reconoció en una entrevista que<strong> la GameBoy fue su gran compañera de infancia</strong> y admite que la conserva aún, guardada en algún rincón de su casa. Sus sagas favoritas son <em>Call of Duty</em> y <em>Tom Raider.</em></p><h3>Justin Bieber</h3><p>El cantanate canadiense es otro artista más que se suma a los famosos <em>gamers</em>. <a href=\"https://www.20minutos.es/minuteca/justin-bieber/\">Bieber</a> ha admitido más de una vez que <strong>es fan de los <em>Call of Duty</em>, de <em>Mario Kart</em> y de <em>Halo</em>,</strong> asegurando que es un jugador habitual en su tiempo libre.</p><h3>Jessica Alba</h3><p>Otra de las caras famosas de Hollywood que disfruta de la industria de los videojuegos en su tiempo libre es <a href=\"https://www.20minutos.es/minuteca/jessica-alba/\">Jessica Alba</a>. La actriz pasó su infancia disfrutando de títulos como <em>Bomberman, Pac-Man, Super Mario</em> y <em>The Legend of Zelda.</em> Además, ha asegurado que <strong><em>Wii Fit</em> le fue de mucha ayuda tras dar a luz</strong> para recuperar su figura.</p>"
        },
        "date": {
           "__text": "2018-11-05T11:24:38+01:00"
        },
        "creator": {
           "__cdata": "INÉS LÓPEZ"
        },
        "_rdf:about": "https://www.20minutos.es/videojuegos/noticia/famosos-gamer-cantante-lady-gaga-club-aficionados-videojuegos-3482700/0/"
     },
     {
        "title": {
           "__cdata": "Blizzard cede a las peticiones de los fans y transforma al Rey Esqueleto en conserje"
        },
        "link": "https://www.20minutos.es/videojuegos/noticia/leoric-conserje-llegara-a-heroes-of-the-storm-3483141/0/",
        "description": {
           "__cdata": "<p>20MINUTOS.ES</p> <ul><li>El diseño lo creó un aficionado al videojuego para un concurso que realizó la compañía.</li><li>Leoric, el Rey Esqueleto, se podrá vestir de conserje y atacará con una fregona.</li><li><a href=\"https://www.20minutos.es/videojuegos/noticia/esports-videojuegos-mueven-millones-dota2-league-of-legends-counter-strike-3373956/0/\">Videojuegos que mueven millones en los eSports.</a></li></ul><p><img src=\"https://cdn.20m.es/img2/recortes/2018/11/05/817958-620-282.jpg?v=20181105145815\" width=\"620\" height=\"282\" alt=\"Heroes of the Storm\" /></p><p>La compañía <a href=\"https://www.20minutos.es/videojuegos/minuteca/blizzard/\">Blizzard</a> ha anunciado este lunes que va a utilizar <strong>el diseño de un aficionado</strong> al videojuego <a href=\"https://www.20minutos.es/videojuegos/noticia/universo-warcraft-llega-heroes-of-the-storm-vale-alterac-3359586/0/\"><em>Heroes of the Storm</em></a> en uno de sus personajes. En concreto, ha afirmado que va a utilizar el traje de conserje para el personaje Leoric, el Rey Esqueleto.</p><p>Se trata de una versión cómica del Rey Esqueleto, <strong>original del universo de <em>Diablo</em>,</strong> en el que se vestirá de conserje y utilizará la fregona para pelar. Además, su fantasma irá fregando mientras camina.<br /><br /></p><div><blockquote class=\"twitter-tweet\" data-lang=\"es\"><p dir=\"ltr\">Our first Nexus-Born Hero, Gameplay Updates, Mounts, Skins, and much more. See what’s coming to Heroes of the Storm with our BlizzCon 2018 announcements! <a href=\"https://t.co/37JSHUJiTV\">pic.twitter.com/37JSHUJiTV</a></p>— Heroes of the Storm (@BlizzHeroes) <a href=\"https://twitter.com/BlizzHeroes/status/1058429225974124545?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw\">2 de noviembre de 2018</a></blockquote></div><p>Las ilustraciones originales de este gracioso diseño provienen de <strong>un concurso que realizó la compañía</strong> en conmemoración del primer aniversario del <a href=\"https://www.20minutos.es/videojuegos/minuteca/videojuegos/\">videojuego</a>. En ellas se pueden ver todos los movimientos del personaje que llegará a la comunidad.</p><div><blockquote class=\"twitter-tweet\" data-lang=\"es\"><p dir=\"ltr\">\"All shall be cleaned!\"<br />Winner of the 1-year Heroes anniversary drawing contest.<br />Source: <a href=\"https://t.co/YNmDZNiAnU\">https://t.co/YNmDZNiAnU</a> <a href=\"https://t.co/0h0Oe0MQTb\">pic.twitter.com/0h0Oe0MQTb</a></p>— Heroes of the Storm (@BlizzHeroes) <a href=\"https://twitter.com/BlizzHeroes/status/749981228263149569?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw\">4 de julio de 2016</a></blockquote></div><p>Desde que salió a la luz los fans han querido jugar con este <strong>posible traje para el personaje huesudo</strong>, pidiendo en numerosas ocasiones a la compañía que lo incluyera en el videojuego.</p>"
        },
        "date": {
           "__text": "2018-11-05T14:52:06+01:00"
        },
        "creator": {
           "__cdata": "20MINUTOS.ES"
        },
        "_rdf:about": "https://www.20minutos.es/videojuegos/noticia/leoric-conserje-llegara-a-heroes-of-the-storm-3483141/0/"
     },
     {
        "title": {
           "__cdata": "'SEGA Heroes', un juego para móviles con algunos de sus populares personajes"
        },
        "link": "https://www.20minutos.es/videojuegos/noticia/sega-heroes-juego-moviles-3482809/0/",
        "description": {
           "__cdata": "<p>20MINUTOS.ES</p> <ul><li>Será un juego del tipo conecta-3 con personajes como Sonic, Axel Stone, Knuckless y Gum.</li><li>No tiene fecha de estreno, pero para probarlo en iOS o Android deberás preregistrarte.</li></ul><p><img src=\"https://cdn.20m.es/img2/recortes/2018/11/05/817650-620-282.jpg\" width=\"620\" height=\"282\" alt=\"SEGA Heroes\" /></p><p><a title=\"https://www.20minutos.es/videojuegos/minuteca/sega/\" href=\"https://www.20minutos.es/videojuegos/minuteca/sega/\">SEGA</a> ha anunciado este fin de semana <strong>la llegada de</strong> <strong><em>SEGA Heroes</em>,</strong> un juego para móviles con algunos de sus personajes más populares. Si eres fan de SEGA aparca aún tu entusiasmo porque, de momento, el título no tiene fecha de estreno. <br /><br />Se trata de <strong>un juego del tipo conecta-3</strong> que toma prestada la dinámica de <em>Puzzle &amp; Dragons</em>. Tendremos un equipo con tres personajes, que lucharán contra varios enemigos. Para poder atacar tendremos que conectar tres figuras iguales en el panel de juego.<br /><br />¿Qué personajes de SEGA aparecerán en el nuevo juego? Pues no se ha concretado. Lo que se sabe es que sí están vinculados con el nuevo título <strong><em>Sonic the Hedgehog</em>, <em>Super Monkey Ball</em>,<em> Jet Set Radio</em>, <em>Shinobi</em> y<em> Streets of Rage</em> </strong>estarán involucradas. Y esto significa que podremos jugar con personajes como <a title=\"https://www.20minutos.es/videojuegos/minuteca/sonic/\" href=\"https://www.20minutos.es/videojuegos/minuteca/sonic/\">Sonic</a>, Axel Stone, Knuckless y Gum.<br /><br />Recuerda que para ser uno de los primeros en jugar SEGA Heroes en iOS o Android deberás <strong>preregistrarte</strong>. <br /><br />Por cierto que los de SEGA acaban de celebrar los <strong>30 años de la SEGA Mega Drive</strong>. El 30 de octubre de 1988 llegaba al mercado japonés, como producto masivo con el poder de los 16-<em>bit</em>. La competencia de Super Nintendo no triunfó en Japón, pero sí en Europa, donde se lanzó en 1990, y en EE UU.<br /><br /></p>"
        },
        "date": {
           "__text": "2018-11-05T13:46:59+01:00"
        },
        "creator": {
           "__cdata": "20MINUTOS.ES"
        },
        "_rdf:about": "https://www.20minutos.es/videojuegos/noticia/sega-heroes-juego-moviles-3482809/0/"
     }
     
  ]
```

Aquí la estructura de mi tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver, solo agrega 1 registro.

Comment: y que error te lanza?

Comment: Como dice @JuanL, qué sale en los logs?

Comment: asi es.. que te dicen

Comment: Al ejecutar el codigo php no me lanza ningún error. O no se de que manera encontrarlo. Alguna sugerencia? estoy usando Xampp

Comment: Mira esta respuesta y modifica tu consulta https://stackoverflow.com/a/17053489/236345

Comment: comentas que algunos datos no se guardaan, no?

Comment: ahora si me lanza un error.. 

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'gamer': la cantante Lady Gaga, fan de 'Bayonetta', se suma al club de los aficio' at line 1

Comment: supongo que es por las comillas dentro del texto json?

Comment: asi es, dentro del valor de __cdata, contienen una "cadena" y esa cadena comillas simples ' '

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda!!